How much horizontal force would it take to keep an object from slipping, using surface area?
I'm trying to figure out the horizontal force ($F_{P}$) needed to keep an object from slipping for a claw mechanism I'm designing. The given variables are the coefficient of static friction ($\mu_{_{s}}$), mass ($m$), and surface area of contact ($w\times l$), as seen in the attached image: I know that the pinching force equation is $F_{p}=\frac{F_{0}}{2\mu_{_{s}}}$, so presumably, the equation would be $F_{p}=\frac{mg}{2\mu_{_{s}}}$. The problem with this equation, though, is that it doesn't take surface area into account. I know that surface area doesn't affect friction force, but it still feels significant. If the object was, for example, a sphere, wouldn't you need more force? My next guess was that you'd simply divide $\frac{mg}{2\mu_{_{s}}}$ by the surface area, making the equation $F_{p}=\frac{mg}{2\mu_{_{s}}wl}$, but that doesn't make sense, either. Using that equation, it would take more force to hold a block of $0.5$ by $0.5$ meters up than it would to hold a sphere (assuming one point of contact on each plate) of the same mass.
So, my question is: what equation would you use to calculate necessary pinching force to keep the object from slipping?

The friction equation is independent of surface area, that's why it doesn't show up.  Cars on roads are not ideal conditions so fat tires work better.  No effect on pieces of square steel.

High school friction is independent of area. This is a Lie we tell to children https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children in reality there are many physical mechanisms relating to friction. To take your sphere example further, suppose it was a diamond, and it embedded itself in the friction plates? Sadly/happily  the answer to a specific issue is testing, not calculation.

You are only confusing force with pressure.
Yes it is true that F, required to hold the object, is constant
$$F>\frac{mg}{2\mu_{_{s}}}$$
But pressure is force, F, divided by the area.
$$P=\frac{F}{IL} \ , \quad P>\frac{mg}{2\mu*IL}$$
This is if we ignore the fact that other parameters, such as surface materials, contact type and size, etc., have an impact on the friction index.
